# seems's like torch' cuda command not using external GPU but internal GPU

Tags: pytorch

[image]

I don't know why
I installed it with this command
pip install torch===1.5.0 torchvision===0.6.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

and cause error but anyway it install

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torchaudio 0.10.2 requires torch==1.10.2, but you have torch 1.5.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed torch-1.5.0 torchvision-0.6.0

and on code,

also, when I typed same command

print(torch.cuda.is_available())
torch.tensor([0.12, 0.32]).cuda()

on Google colab with basic gpu
it result instantly
but on my local computer it takes 10minute...

I checked task manager and saw that my internal GPU takes almost 40% but not my external GPU.

Comment: The performance of Pytorch on your computer is not a CUDA programming question and should not be tagged as such